# <!DOCTYPE html> shrinks my website's content

Tags: html, css, dom, doctype

Using **!DOCTYPE html** shrinks my website's first section whose height is given as 120%. I tried all the solutions in stack overflow like making HTML and body's height to 100% but nothing worked.

If I use the below CSS it shrinks the first section

```
.first-section{
   height: 120%;
}
```

If I use the below CSS it works properly

```
.first-section{
   height: 600px;
}
```

If i use **px** instead of **percentage**,  it works properly. I want my first section to work on percentage values.

Comment: I think you can use a reset css . this is an example [Css Reset](https://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
.first-section{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Your body or your div element with the "first-section" class can get unwanted paddings or margins.

Answer (score -1):

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>` Should not effect the way your page looks or behaves.`<!DOCTYPE HTML>` simply tells the browser that the document being rendered is an html document.

Comment: false, the doctype does affect rendering and can send the browser into quirks mode

Comment: Most if not all browsers have old-style rendering (aka Quirks mode) and new-style rendering (Standards Compliant mode). Setting a DOCTYPE changes the mode. More info: https://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: then why it shrink my page content? It happens only when I include **doctype**.

Comment: Short answer: it does so because the rendering modes work in different ways, with different defaults; long answer is a painful history lesson. You should set a proper DOCTYPE first, and then write/design your CSS to do what you want to achieve.